# XCode 5 No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector 'adjustTextViewByKeyboardState:keyboardInfo:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have a View Controller which has a single text view field. I have 3 different such controllers but one of them gets this error in the custom class.

I've copied the code from the working VCs and it still gives the same error: 
No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector 'adjustTextViewByKeyboardState:keyboardInfo:'

I'm assuming that there must be some attribute in storyboard that is causing this but I cannot see anything.

I'm a relative newbie in this so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Somebody is calling adjustText.. Function on an object of ur xxx class. Is that correct or wrong? Can u show some code? Or search for that function

Comment: Based on the method name, it adjust textview either position or size based on keyboard show or hidden state. Please check if in your view controller, are you responding to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification or UIKeyboardWillHideNotification where the given method is called. It appeared as if you are missed copying the implementation of the method but you are calling it somewhere.

Comment: As I said ... I am using exactly the same code in all 3 classes (other than the names). I cannot see how that code can be the problem since two other view controllers work without problem. The problem must be in the Storyboard configuration.

Comment: I fixed this by creating a new View Controller ... never figured out what the problem with the original one was.